# How to reference modelValue from a function in a VUE componenet

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I am using **Vite** to build my **Vue SFCs**. I need to access the `modelValue` inside a `function` declared by the component. How do I do it?

Here is what I tried:

```html
<script setup>
defineProps([ 'modelValue' ]);
defineEmits([ 'udpate:model-value' ]);

function portPlaceholder() {
    // ERROR THROWN HERE, modelValue is not defined
    if ( modelValue?.type === 'example' ) return 'something';
    if ( modelValue?.type === 'other' ) return 'something-else';
    return 'default-something';
}

</script>
<template>
    Some input: <input type="text" :placeholder="portPlaceholder()" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to assign the define props to a prop constant the use that constant to access the prop field, and use computed property instead of the function :

```html
<script setup>
import {computed} from 'vue';

const props = defineProps([ 'modelValue' ]);
const emit = defineEmits([ 'udpate:model-value' ]);

const portPlaceholder = computed(()=>{
    if ( props.modelValue?.type === 'example' ) return 'something';
    if ( props.modelValue?.type === 'other' ) return 'something-else';
    return 'default-something';
 })

</script>
<template>
    Some input: <input type="text" :placeholder="portPlaceholder" />
</template>
```